# Adobe Encore - I have problem with add Arabic subtitle to my project

Tags: subtitles, adobe, encore

I try make DVD of movie with Arabic translation I add my subtitle , But it doesn't look nice as supposed I try Every thing but I can't fix problem

Any suggestion 
Thank you in advance

Here is screen  shot of my problem

[image]

Comment: As currently asked, there isn't really enough detail to give a reliable answer to this question. Can you please add screen captures of what the problem is you are experiencing?  Is the problem consistent on multiple playback devices?

Comment: I add screen shot of my problem